# Is it possible to sudo into a server with ssh only using a ppk or pem file?

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'm trying to make a change to a read only file (php.ini) on a server. The developers told me I could use the ppk file in order to make the change. I don't have the root password for the server. I only have a username, server ip, ppk and pem file. Is this possible? Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows use PuTTY and the ppk. Read the documentation for that. If you are on Linux open a terminal and run:

```
ssh -i path_to_pem.pem username@server_ip
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm on a mac using ssh to log into a Linux server. I used the second command but it still asks me for a password when I try to save the read only file. Should this be happening?

Comment: If you are prompted for a password when actually running the ssh command then it is a password protected key and that is normal - there is no way around it, you have to be given the password. There shouldn't be anything stopping you saving the file though, regardless of read only permissions. How are you saving it?

Comment: The ssh command runs fine. The file is read only so it wont let me save my changes without running it with sudo. The sudo command makes me enter a password. Is there a way around it or another way to save the file? I'm using vim to edit the file if that makes a difference.

Comment: The password for the sudo command on Mac is just the password of your Mac user, which you login to your laptop with.

Comment: I'm using sudo on the linux server that I'm remote logging into, not on my mac. I don't have the password when I use sudo. I was only given a ppk and pem file. Is there a way to use those files to authenticate a change to a read only file? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. If you do not have the sudo password then you cannot edit the file. The ppk or pem will not help you, as they only enable you to login as a specific user (not root).

Comment: Okay, I'm new to ssh so I was unsure if that was possible. Thanks again for taking the time to answer me!